# Can you pre-check wordpress categories?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy, which has 2 terms. I'd like to have both of these checked/selected by default when someone creates a new post. Is this possible? I've searched but found no solutions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing directly meant for that (that I can think of), but there is very close in purpose function [`get_default_post_to_edit()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_default_post_to_edit/).

Since for the purpose of new post creation it makes post appear in DB before it is even saved for the first time (as auto draft) we can tinker with its filters a bit to make it happen:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', function ( $content, $post ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( 'post' === $screen->base && 'add' === $screen->action && 'code-project' === $screen->post_type ) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'plugin', 'code-project-type' );
    }

    return $content;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. To clarify for others, in the example above "code-project" is the custom post type and "code-project-type" is the custom taxonomy and "plugin" is the taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve it for specific Role:

```
    add_filter( 'default_content', function ( $content, $post ) {
if ( current_user_can( 'role_one' ) ){
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( 'post' === $screen->base && 'add' === $screen->action && 'events' === $screen->post_type ) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'Světu mír', 'přání' );

    }
}

    return $content;
}, 10, 2 );
```